# How to render a dependent component on same page as parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an 'upload' component that uses 'react-dropzone' which allows users to upload files. (Upoad box is the 'drag-n'drop box')

```
return (
    <div className="section" id="uploadSection">
      <div style={containerStyle}>
        <form style={formStyle} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <UploadBox setFiles={setFiles} fileLimit={fileLimit} setAlert={setAlert} />
          <input
            className="upload-btn"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit files"
            style={{ opacity: btnOpacity }}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Once the users click on 'submit files', I use 'history.push' to navigate to 'resultspage'. Which uses the uploaded files from the 'upload' component.

```
history.push("/resultspage", { files: filesRef.current });
```

'resultspage' component needs the files to render, if files are empty, 'resultspage' doesn't run. So what I'm currently trying to do is render the 'reportpage' right below my 'upload' component, instead of navigating to a new page. I'm not sure what to do, I've tried to replace the 'history.push' line with simply returning the 'reportpage' component, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you can put that component just below the form and track using state, that if user submits and the files are valid then just show that reportPage component else do not show the page

Comment: Have you tried checking that `filesRef.current` does have a value before and after you dropped the file?

Comment: Along with verifying that `filesRef` is updated with a current value have you also verified you are sending route state correctly for the route transition? What routing/navigation package are you using? Can you share how you've setup all your routing?